# Unit tests (Quick/Nimble) - (no tests found)

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, appcode, quick-nimble

I have problem with unit testing. When I run tests, it ends up with `"No tests found"`.
I am using `AppCode` and `Quick/Nimble` framework for unit testing, but it doesn't work in XCode either.

I have `XCTest/Kiwi` run configuration with Target: MyAppTests, Configuration: Development and Class: All test classes (it doesn't work even with particular test class specified).
Nothing much more configured as far as I know.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am not sure what other kind of info/configuration I should provide.. thanks

Edit:
Sample unit test code

```
import Quick
import Nimble
@testable import FigurePOS

class DateFormatterTest: QuickSpec
{
    override func spec()
    {
        describe("formatting dates") {
            it("should print correct date") {

                var c = DateComponents()
                c.year = 2016
                c.month = 5
                c.day = 24
                c.hour = 4
                c.minute = 33
                c.second = 12

                let gregorian = NSCalendar(identifier: .gregorian)!
                let date = gregorian.date(from: c)!

                expect(DateFormatter.formatGmt(date)).to(equal("2016-05-24T04:33:12Z"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of one of your Quick test file ? I use Quick and I didn't configured anything special

Comment: Sure, I added sample code to question.

Comment: have you tried in XCode to run "Product -> Build for -> Testing" ?

Comment: What is the difference between Product -> Test and Product -> Build for -> Testing? Anyway, it's the same..

Comment: It's for running unit test specially, sometimes the "diamond" button doesn't appear when I create a new Unit test file with Quick but then it's ok.

Comment: Do you tried to delete Derived Data ?

Answer (score 2):

I use `Quick` + `Nimble` too. The code looks fine to me.

My guess is that the class is not being compiled. Can you go to `Targets` > `AppTests` > `Build Phrases`. Ensure that the `DateFormatterTest` is in `Compile Sources`.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: I have a similar problem. But, the files is in "Compile Sources". It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. I can't remember exactly what I did to fix it, but one of the things I tried was:

Override the spec() method, and add `super.spec()` right on the beginning.

Answer (score -4):

A test class should include  setUp() and tearDown(),and you should call the name of your function as testSpec().Named function use 'test' as beginning.
you can try it.

Comment: Not necessary with Quick, only overriding spec method is required